# How to load an activity indicator before scrollview even appears on my screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I am showing a scrollview on the screen and populating content and before it even appears on my screen i wanted to load a activity indicator view. i know how to do it using webview methods like below but not for scrollview , can somebody help me with the right methods for scrollview.

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

}

(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

}
```

Comment: you want to load activity indicator before the content on scroll view loads?

Comment: content include everything like buttons,labels,textfields? or your content is fixed to some particular items?

Comment: normally,scrollview is just like a uiview, if you are storing the content in an array,then you can display the activity indicator when the array is filled up and ready to go

Comment: What i am doing is loading a webview inside a scrollview and displaying my content on the view .

Comment: what methods do i need to use for that purpose ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75981/discussion-between-t-77-and-tej).

Answer (score 1):

There are no such methods for the `scrollView` because it is just a container for other views, there is no implicit loading involved like with the `webView`.

Therefore, you will have to keep track of the state of the content manually. One solution would be to add the `activityIndicator` in `viewWillAppear:` or `awakeFromNib` (depending if you are implementing your logic in the `viewController` or a custom `UIView`).

Then when your content is loaded, for example in the `webView` `delegate` methods, you stop the animating and, eventually, make the `webView` visible, if you want this kind of animation.

Let me know if you need more help or have any questions.

Comment: Hi catalina , thanks for your help . It is working fine as you mentioned in viewwillappear but it doesn't get stopped after webviewdidfinishload method , can i call in some other view method ?

Comment: You mean that is not the method where you want to stop it or you tried to stop it and it did not work?

Comment: i tried to stop but it didn't work in the webviewdidfinsihload method and the spinner keeps spinning even after loading the data .